# Javascript sum of highest 6 values in an array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, sum

I have an array of roughly 10 values, and I was wondering if there was any way with JS or JQuery to add up the highest 6 values and get a total.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here:

```
var top6Total = arr
                .map(function (v) { return +v; })
                .sort(function (a,b) { return a-b; })
                .slice( -6 )
                .reduce(function (a,b) { return a+b; });
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/bPwYB/

(Note: You would have to [polyfill](https://github.com/kriskowal/es5-shim) `.reduce()` for IE8.)

Comment: A small note, sorting the whole array just to get the six maximum values might not always be the best. In this case the array only has 10 elements so It's ok.

Comment: @MrAzulay If you want the top 6 values, you need to sort the whole array. There is no alternative here.

Comment: Note: The sort destroys the original array. I don't know if that is a problem in this case. It can be avoided by adding `.slice(0)` to copy the array.

Comment: @ŠimeVidas No, If you want the six max values you can just get the six max values. Of course there are alternatives, you don't need to sort the whole array when you are not interested in the whole array. Look into sorting algorithms if you do not believe me.

Comment: @ŠimeVidas if the array has even a modest number of elements, making six simple passes over the array (or one pass with a six-element "largest" list) will be faster than a sort.

Comment: @some Sort doesn't destroy the array itself. Sort "destroys" the order of the elements in the array. The array (as in, the array object) is preserved. So, references to the array keep functioning after the sort.

Comment: @Pointy Yes. The one-pass top-6-list solution could be implemented with `.reduce()`... (I think)

Comment: @ŠimeVidas Bad choice of words from my side (English isn't my native language). It rearrange the order (like I said in a comment to another answer). The thing is, that if `arr[0]` was _number of visitors on Monday_, it isn't after the sort (unless Monday had the fewest visitors). Since it isn't obvious that the original array is modified, and it can lead to hard to find bugs, I always copy the array if I'm not creating it inside the function where I sort it.

Comment: For some reason this doesn't want to work on my site, I have it on a completely blank page and it still doesn't work... Works fine on jsfiddle. Here is the code

`<script type="text/javascript">

var arr = [99,2,4,7,1,9,34,24,11];

var top6Total = arr
                .sort(function ( a, b ) { return a - b; })
                .slice( -6 )
                .reduce(function ( a, b ) { return a + b;});

document.write(top6total);

​</script>`

Comment: Firebug says the following error
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL 
on line 11 which is the document.write line

Comment: @user1599318 Since you are using firebug, why don't you use `console.log(top6total)` and look at the console view?

Comment: seems like it might have sorted itself out now, could've been something to do with spacing... thank you though

Comment: Ok so now I have a different issue, instead of adding up the top 6 values it's just displaying them this could be because I get the array differently, here is how:

`var selected = new Array();
$('.points option:selected').each(function() {
    selected.push($(this).val());
 });`

It gets the array from a number of dropdowns, but I'm not sure if that's a different type of array than the one you specified?

Comment: The value returned for me is 100100100100100100 (my top 6 highest values are 100,100,100,100,100,100 by default). Is there something I'm doing wrong?

Comment: @user1599318 You're having this issue because your array **does not contain numbers**, but strings representing numbers. (`100+100=200`, but `'100'+'100'='100100'`) You have to coerce those string values to the *Number* type first. I've added a `.map()` invocation that takes care of that, to my answer above.

Comment: @ŠimeVidas works like a charm! I was guessing it was something like that but couldn't figure out how to change it. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 5):

Simpler way (to understand obviously :) ) is

```
var arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]; // your array

arr = arr.sort(function (a,b) { return a - b; });

var sum=0;
for(var i=0;i<6;i++) {
sum+=arr[i];
}

alert(sum);
```

Comment: I like the solution @Šime Vidas came up with, but not every time is good to write slick code. Yours works also. so +1

Comment: Note: The sort rearranges the original array. I don't know if that's a problem in this case, but it is easy to circumvent by adding a `.slice(0)` between `arr` and `sort`.

Answer (score 1):

```
var sortedArr = arr.sort(function (a,b) { return b - a; });
var sum = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++)
    sum += sortedArr[i];
```

Answer (score 1):

Answer edited to avoid the problem of 'overwriting the function with the result' identified by @pimvdb, and kindly explained by @some (in comments, below).

A simple approach that should cover almost all browsers (I *think*) is to use a function to sum the array values:

```
var vals = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];

function arraySum(arr) {
    if (!arr) {
        return false;
    }
    else {
        var sum = 0;
        for (var i = 0, len = arr.length; i < len; i++) {
            sum += arr[i];
        }
        return sum;
    }
}
sum = arraySum(vals.sort(function(a, b) {
    return b - a;
}).slice(0, 6));

console.log(sum);​
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/txXGJ/1/).

Though, for those browsers in which it's available, `reduce()` is far, *far* simpler.

Comment: I'm not sure if overwriting the function with the result is a very good idea.

Comment: @pimvdb: okay, this is possibly one of those times where self-teaching becomes a problem; I'm a little ashamed to say that I don't understand your comment... =/

Comment: @DavidThomas You name the function sum and you do `sum = sum(...)`. That works in an eval-environment (like the Firefox console) but don't work in real code.

Comment: @some: ah! So, naming the *variable* the same name as the *function* is the (main) problem?

Comment: Yes, that was what pimvdb was commenting on.

Comment: I have to modify my comment above. It is actually possible to overwrite the function with a value (last week I read about the differences in eval and normal mode and remembered it wrong). It is however bad practice.

Comment: Sorry :) yes, that's what I meant. It works but it's a little bit confusing if you use the same variable for both.