# How to get sum of highest 5 values of an array using Javascript or Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an array of 6 values where 6th value is optional (i.e. if user does not input 6th value, the first 5 values will be calculated). I want to sum highest 5 values of them.

My Javascript Code:

```
function calculate_merit_point(){

   var s1 = eval(document.getElementById('sub_no1').value);
   var s2 = eval(document.getElementById('sub_no2').value);
   var s3 = eval(document.getElementById('sub_no3').value);
   var s4 = eval(document.getElementById('sub_no4').value);
   var s5 = eval(document.getElementById('sub_no5').value);
   var s6 = eval(document.getElementById('sub_no6').value);

   var vals = [s1,s2,s3,s4,s5,s6];

  function arraySum(arr) {
      if (!arr) {
          return false;
      } else {
          var sum = 0;
          for (var i = 0, len = arr.length; i < len; i++) {
              sum += arr[i];
          }
          return sum;
      }
  }


  sum = arraySum(vals.sort(function(a, b) {
      return b - a;
  }).slice(0, 5));


  if(isNaN(tt)){
      $('#agr').text('0');
  } else {
      $('#agr').text(sum);
  }


}
```

Now suppose

```
s1 = 30
s2 = 31
s3 = 32
s4 = 33
s5 = 34
s6 = 35
```

It should be `31+32+33+34+35 = 165`. but it is displaying the value 162.

As per my requirement (6th value optional), if I do not give any value to `s6`, it is displaying the value **228**.

I have tried [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12019803/javascript-sum-of-highest-6-values-in-an-array), but if I do not give the 6th (optional) value, it is showing the value `0`. If I give the value 35 in s6, it is showing sum value 233.

**What should I do ?**

---

**UPDATE & RESOLVED**

My code was correct. But something was creating problem with the code `eval()`. I replaced it with `Number()` and it was resolved.

**Thank you all.**

Comment: That is one of the worst ways to start a question.

Comment: @trincot Could you please teach me how to start ? I am here to solve my problem not for writing a literature. If you have the answer please write.

Comment: With those values it displays 165: https://jsfiddle.net/gebL90bk/ If it shows 162, the problem is somewhere else.

Comment: Unrelated, but `eval()` is probably the worst way to convert strings to integers.

Comment: @Raj, don't start with "Please do not mark this question as DUPLICATE". This alone will already attract downvotes.

Comment: @trincot Thanks, but for me answer is more important than votes.

Comment: You are more likely to get an answer if you write a good question.

Comment: @JJJ StackOverflow has many users who find and mark a question `Possibly Duplicate` and close it. However, I am modifying my question to get the answer. Thanks to you all.

Comment: You can't prevent closing by just saying "don't close this". It won't help and it's only going to annoy people.

Answer (score 0):

You can sum more easily with `reduce`, and subtract the highest value with `Math.max` using this ES6 code:

```js
var vals = [30,31,32,33,34,35,36];
// Get sum
var sum = vals.reduce( (a,b) => a+b, 0 );
// Subtract highest value
if (vals.length == 6) sum -= Math.max(...vals);
// Output result
console.log(sum);
```

Here is that code integrated with the element names you mention in your code, but using jQuery also for the first part:

```js
function calculate_merit_point(){
   // Get all six input elements by using jQuery with a smarter selector:
   var vals = $('[id^=sub_no]').map(function () { 
     return parseInt($(this).val()); // get the value as numeric for each of them
   }).get().filter(n => !isNaN(n)); // filter the result to get real numbers only
   
   // get sum
   var sum = vals.reduce( (a,b) => a+b, 0 );
   // Remove greatest value from it if we have 6 numbers
   if (vals.length == 6) sum -= Math.max(...vals);
   // Output the result. 
   $('#agr').text(sum);
}

calculate_merit_point();
$('input').on('input', calculate_merit_point);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="sub_no1" value="1"><br>
<input id="sub_no2" value="2"><br>
<input id="sub_no3" value="3"><br>
<input id="sub_no4" value="4"><br>
<input id="sub_no5" value="5"><br>
<input id="sub_no6" value="6"><br>
<hr>
Sum: <span id="agr"></span>
```

You can adjust the values when running the above snippet and the sum will adapt.

#### ES5 equivalent

For when you don't have ES6 support:

```js
function calculate_merit_point(){
   // Get all six input elements by using jQuery with a smarter selector:
   var vals = $('[id^=sub_no]').map(function () { 
     return parseInt($(this).val()); // get the value as numeric for each of them
   }).get().filter(function (n) {
     return !isNaN(n);  // filter the result to get real numbers only
   });
   
   // get sum
   var sum = vals.reduce(function (a,b) {
       return a+b;
   }, 0);
   // Remove greatest value from it if we have 6 numbers
   if (vals.length == 6) sum -= Math.max.apply(Math, vals);
   // Output the result. 
   $('#agr').text(sum);
}

calculate_merit_point();
$('input').on('input', calculate_merit_point);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="sub_no1" value="1"><br>
<input id="sub_no2" value="2"><br>
<input id="sub_no3" value="3"><br>
<input id="sub_no4" value="4"><br>
<input id="sub_no5" value="5"><br>
<input id="sub_no6" value="6"><br>
<hr>
Sum: <span id="agr"></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

This would be a great opportunity to use `.reduce`. Which will return a single value given an array. While we're "looping" through the array, we will determine the lowest value, and then subtract that from the result. Also, you're clearly using jQuery to apply the `.text()` so, may as well use it to get the `.val()` of each of your inputs. Then we'll use `parseInt` with a check to return `0` in the event of an error/invalid result

**[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/xo1o03vs/)**

**HTML**

```
<input id="sub_no1" value="30" />
<input id="sub_no2" value="31" />
<input id="sub_no3" value="32" />
<input id="sub_no4" value="33" />
<input id="sub_no5" value="34" />
<input id="sub_no6" value="35" />
<p id="agr"></p>
```

**JS**

```
$(function() {
    function calculate_merit_point() {
        var s1 = getValue($('#sub_no1'));
        var s2 = getValue($('#sub_no2'));
        var s3 = getValue($('#sub_no3'));
        var s4 = getValue($('#sub_no4'));
        var s5 = getValue($('#sub_no5'));
        var s6 = getValue($('#sub_no6'));

        var vals = [s1, s2, s3, s4, s5, s6];

        function getValue(el) {
            return parseInt(el.val(), 10) || 0;
        }

        function arraySum(arr) {
            if (!arr) {
                return 0;
            } else {
                var lowest = Infinity;
                return vals.reduce(function(sum, val) {
                    if (val < lowest){ lowest = val; }
                    return sum + val;
                }, 0) - lowest;
            }
        }

        $('#agr').text(arraySum(vals));
    }
    calculate_merit_point();
})
```